# How to connect Sippy SIP server (UDP) via AWS to support ios app background/terminate mode calling

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, sip, voip, amazon-sns

I am working on iOS VOIP Calling app for us based client. But I am facing issue regarding to support calling to background or terminate mode. Apple does not provide support for background mode with UDP protocol. Apple suggests to use TCP to support VOIP notification for background mode support. My client's SPI server (Sippy) is supported only UDP.

Can anyone suggest that is it possible to use AWS?

Is it possible to iOS app send request to AWS then AWS send request to SPI server?

Please suggest me, what should we the option to support VOIP notification with UDP.

Comment: Correct spelling: ' SIP' server and 'SIPpy'. In what scenario's should your app send a request to AWS (which is then relayed to your SIP server?

Comment: When app in background or terminated then send request AWS.

Answer (score 0):

When the app is not running, all your server can do is send a push notification. This is a common way to inform users of an incoming call in VoIP apps.

Comment: Hi, i am new to develop VOIP app, but little confuse to UDP server support to background mode or not?